# OWL intersection vs union

Tags: rdf, owl, set-intersection, set-union

Given the following triples, are the domain and range a union or intersection or something else?

```
<http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask> rdfs:domain <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rdf> .
<http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask> rdfs:domain <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/owl> .
<http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask> rdfs:domain <https://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/#Boolean> .
<http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask> rdfs:range <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rdf> .
<http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask> rdfs:range <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/owl> .
<http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask> rdfs:range <https://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/#Boolean> .
```

In other words, does the `http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask` predicate have three domains, three ranges, and any domain-range pairing <s>is valid</s> *can be inferred*?

---

Edit: The w3.org documentation for [domain](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-rdf-schema-20040210/#ch_domain) and [range](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-rdf-schema-20040210/#ch_range) states:

> Where a property P has more than one `rdfs:domain` property, then the resources denoted by subjects of triples with predicate P are instances of all the classes stated by the `rdfs:domain` properties.
>
> Where P has more than one `rdfs:range` property, then the resources denoted by the objects of triples with predicate P are instances of all the classes stated by the `rdfs:range` properties.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42595841/define-mutiple-domains-ranges-in-a-same-propery-in-owl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can think of it as intersection, but it's a little bit indirect.  When you have a triple

> p rdfs:domain C

it means that whenever you have a triple

> a p b

you can *infer* that

> a rdf:type C

So, when you have

> p rdfs:domain C
>   p rdfs:domain D
>   p rdfs:domain E
>
> a p b

you can *infer*

> a rdf:type C
>   a rdf:type D
>   a rdf:type E

which is the effect of having declared

> p rdfs:domain (C ⊓ D ⊓ E)

Similarly, from **p rdfs:range F** and **a p b** we can infer **b rdf:type F**.

That means that we can answer your final question:

> *In other words, does the `http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask` predicate have three domains, three ranges, and any domain-range pairing is valid?*

OWL isn't about specifying what's "valid" or not in this regard, it's about specifying what you can infer from other data.  If you have:

> p rdfs:domain A
>   p rdfs:domain B
>   p rdfs:domain C
>
> p rdfs:range D
>   p rdfs:range E
>   p rdfs:range F

then from

> a p b

you'll be able to infer

> a rdf:type A
>   a rdf:type B
>   a rdf:type C
>
> b rdf:type D
>   b rdf:type E
>   b rdf:type F

Comment: what is the advantage of intersection over union ?  I mean why owl determined multiple domain / range to be intersection not union?

Comment: @amin  It's not that "owl determined multiple domain / range to be intersection not union".   That multiple domains or ranges end up with intersection semantics is just a consequence of what domain and range axioms mean.  If I say that "p domain X" and "p domain Y", then whenever I see "a p b", I can infer that "a rdf:type X" and that "a rdf:type Y".  But that's exactly what it means for "a" to be in the intersection of X and Y.