# OWL domain range union

Tags: rdf, owl, set-union

From a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793788/owl-intersection-vs-union) I gained an understanding of how *intersection* works among multiple domains and ranges of a predicate.

It seems that *union* is the more common way to handle this scenario, so now I'm wondering what different inferences are made from a union of domains or ranges.

Given `p rdfs:domain (C ∪ D ∪ E)` and the triple `a p b`, what is inferred about `a`?

Comment: It is inferred that `a` belongs to the union of `C, D` and `E`. Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who are not well versed in Set theory (like myself) I will provide some explanation of what I think it means for `a` to belong to the union of `C`, `D`, and `E`.

- The type of `a` is at least one of `C` or `D` or `E`.
- The type of `a` may be more than one of `C` and `D` and `E`.

  - For example, `a` may be type `C` and type `E` (or may be all three types).
- If `C`, `D`, and `E` all have a common superclass `S`, then `a` is also of type `S`.
- Given the information in the question, there is no more precise way to define the type of `a` beyond these "maybes". Specifically, we cannot infer that `a` has more than one type, but we cannot infer that `a` has less than three types either.